# UITabBarController icons not showing up

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, interface-builder, uitabbar, xcode10.1

I have an app that has a `UITabBarController` with four view controllers embedded.

I've created icons for both normal and selected states and set them via the interface builder. The sizes of the individual icons vary slightly according to the new [design guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/#tab-bar-icon-size). Also the icons are PDFs. I initially set it's Render As property to Template Image.

The titles of the tab bar icons show up but not the icons.

[image]

But they do show up in the interface builder though.

[image]

Then I set the Render As to both Original and Default but neither worked.

I'm using Xcode 10.1. What am I missing here?

Comment: Something went wrong with your PDF Size please try to follow this step https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-scaled-images-with-pdf-vectors/

Comment: Your pdf image size seems to be small.. Please try to use proper format size for images

Answer (score 2):

It seems problem with image you are using. try setting different insets to image and tab bar icon will appear.

i have set some inset for icon and icon appeared in simulator.so you will need proper icon image for asset or would required proper inset for icons.

[image]

Comment: Turns out something had gone wrong when exporting the PDFs. I exported them again and they showed up fine.

Comment: Cool, Happy Coding..!!